# re-position DIV menu items on width change

Tags: css, html, menu, width, positioning

Say I have a menu bar at the top of my webpage.

Each menu item is in its own DIV, and these are laid out horizontally, with each menu item DIV side-by-side.

Now, as you shrink the width of the browser, there comes a point where the browser width will be less than the width of this menu bar.

What I'd like to do is to have the very last menu item (DIV) move down to the next line when this happens, and each consecutive last menu item do the same as the width of the browser continues to shrink, until all the menu items end up stacked from top to bottom.

I'm not sure how to do this using CSS.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Do the menu items need to fill the entire width of the menu?  Or are they a static width?  You could just float the menu items left within the menu div.

Comment: What I have so far is a UL list of menu items. The menu items do not need to fill the entire width. Only 5 items and preferably pushed to the right side of the window (as the logo would be on the left). But as the width of the browser is shrunk, the end of the menu needs to drop down until it is so narrow that they are all vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Menu1
            </li>
            <li>
                Menu2
            </li>
            <li>
                Menu3
            </li>
            <li>
                Menu4
            </li>
            <li>
                Menu5
            </li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    min-width:200px;
    background-color:green;
}

#container ul li{
    width:50px;
    height:22px;
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid black;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jU44m/

Comment: Thanks PGR - once I changed the min-width from 200 to 100, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, All of the menu items should be in one larger div, and to make this div resize when the page is resized, set its width value to a percentage. Set the height value of this div to auto so that it will expand when the items fall down (sizing can be done with padding) like this:

```
#menu {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```